# yarn permission problems on OSX high sierra

Tags: macos, permissions, yarnpkg

I'm really scratching my head on this one, and have spent around 1.5 days on trying to resolve the problem

the problem I think has to do with permissions that somehow got reset - 
I suspect it happened after I got boot camp assistant to partition for windows dual boot

**Environment:**

Writing selenium test cases in typescript, using Alsatian and Zalenium frameworks over ts-node - the following command being used to initialise the test runner

```
yarn run ts-node Tests/runner.ts --tap
```

yarn environment is running through brew

package.json:

```
{  
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.8",
    "alsatian": "^2.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "tap-spec": "^4.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tslib": "1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

runner.ts:

```
import tapSpec = require('tap-spec');
import { TestSet, TestRunner } from "alsatian";
import { config as dotenv } from 'dotenv';

(async () =>
{
    // Load up any pseudo environment variables
    dotenv({ path: __dirname + '/../.env' });

    // Setup the alsatian test runner
    let testRunner = new TestRunner();
    let tapStream = testRunner.outputStream;
    let testSet = TestSet.create();
    testSet.addTestsFromFiles('/**/*/*.spec.ts');

    // This will output a human readable report to the console.
    tapStream.pipe(tapSpec()).pipe(process.stdout);

    // Runs the tests
    await testRunner.run(testSet);
})()
.catch(e =>
{
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

**Problem:**

I suspect the problems started after I installed dual boot windows using bootcamp assistant

I worked in windows for 3-4 days on another project and when I came back, started getting permission problems

initially they were along the lines of `{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/Library/Application Support/xxxx'`

which I resolved using chmod as stated below - now I'm stuck - read points 7 and 8, I don't know whats causing the problem - but I suspect it's yarn permissions

I had - also updated to typescript 2.7.1 earlier because I'm using the option  "strictPropertyInitialization": false, in tsconfig - initially I thought that had cause some problem, but reverting to 2.6.2 hasn't resolved it

1. removed and rebuilt node_modules
2. ran first aid from disk utility on partition
3. reset permissions : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538
4. re-installed yarn
5. re-installed brew
6. granted each complained folder sudo chmod -R 777 '/Library/Application Support', now complaining about no access to '/System/Library/User Template' , cannot use chmod here because I get the error, operation not allowed
7. yarn run ts-node Tests/runner.ts --tap gives:

   warning package.json: No license field
   $ /Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/.bin/ts-node Tests/runner.ts --tap
   { Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/System/Library/User Template'
       at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:924:18)
       at GlobSync._readdir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:288:41)
       at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:267:20)
       at GlobSync._readdir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:276:17)
       at GlobSync._processReaddir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:137:22)
       at GlobSync._process (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)0
       at GlobSync._processReaddir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:207:10)
       at GlobSync._process (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)
       at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:380:10)
       at GlobSync._process (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
     errno: -13,
     code: 'EACCES',
     syscall: 'scandir',
     path: '/System/Library/User Template' }
   error Command failed with exit code 1.
   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
8. sudo yarn run ts-node Tests/runner.ts --tap gives:

   { Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, scandir '/dev/fd/13'
       at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:924:18)
       at GlobSync._readdir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:288:41)
       at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:267:20)
       at GlobSync._readdir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:276:17)
       at GlobSync._processReaddir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:137:22)
       at GlobSync._process (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)
       at GlobSync._processReaddir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:207:10)
       at GlobSync._process (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)
       at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:380:10)
       at GlobSync._process (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
     errno: -9,
     code: 'EBADF',
     syscall: 'scandir',
     path: '/dev/fd/13' }
   error Command failed with exit code 1.

**UPDATE 1 - 19 FEB 2017:**

I've placed a test.ts file - which does nothing but print to console , if I call that from yarn ts-node, that works fine

```
yarn run ts-node Tests/test.ts
```

output:

```
yarn run v1.3.2
warning package.json: No license field
$ /Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/.bin/ts-node Tests/test.ts
this is a test
✨  Done in 0.61s.
```

test.ts:

```
(async () =>
{
    console.log("this is a test");

})()
.catch(e =>
{
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

I have also attempted, what the comment has suggested by @[ILI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499581/lll) - I fixed the permissions using First Aid in disk utility on the mac partition ,  since brew no longer supports sudo, I uninstalled yarn from brew, and added it to global packages using

```
sudo yarn install yarn -g
```

but still have the same EACCESS error - Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/Library/Application Support/OpenVPN/profile'

Also tried running yarn --verbose, didn't get much detail from there

```
yarn run --verbose ts-node Tests/runner.ts --tap
yarn run v1.3.2
warning package.json: No license field
verbose 0.331 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/.npmrc".
verbose 0.331 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/.npmrc".
verbose 0.331 Checking for configuration file "/usr/local/etc/npmrc".
verbose 0.332 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/.npmrc".
verbose 0.332 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/.npmrc".
verbose 0.332 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/.npmrc".
verbose 0.332 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/.npmrc".
verbose 0.332 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/.npmrc".
verbose 0.332 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/.npmrc".
verbose 0.333 Checking for configuration file "/Users/.npmrc".
verbose 0.333 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.333 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.334 Found configuration file "/Users/dshamim/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.334 Checking for configuration file "/usr/local/etc/yarnrc".
verbose 0.334 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.334 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.334 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.335 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.337 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/Projects/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.338 Checking for configuration file "/Users/dshamim/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.338 Found configuration file "/Users/dshamim/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.338 Checking for configuration file "/Users/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.34 current time: 2018-02-19T00:39:49.960Z
$ /Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/.bin/ts-node Tests/runner.ts --tap
{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/Library/Application Support/OpenVPN/profile'
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:924:18)
    at GlobSync._readdir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:288:41)
    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:267:20)
    at GlobSync._readdir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:276:17)
    at GlobSync._processReaddir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:137:22)
    at GlobSync._process (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)
    at GlobSync._processReaddir (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:207:10)
    at GlobSync._process (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:380:10)
    at GlobSync._process (/Users/dshamim/Projects/Acurus/ANEX/anex/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/Library/Application Support/OpenVPN/profile' }
verbose 51.049 Error: Command failed with exit code 1.
    at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.3.2/libexec/lib/cli.js:35620:15
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.3.2/libexec/lib/cli.js:92:30)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.3.2/libexec/lib/cli.js:105:13
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: The place where the permissions probably need to be changed is your project directory. Messing with the `Library` permissions is not recommended; you might want to repair them with Disk Utility. Generally if you install yarn with `sudo` and change your project directory with `chmod -R u+w` that should be suitable.

Comment: I have tried the above - same error  - Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/Library/Application Support/OpenVPN/profile'

I've checked my permissions by running ls -le in project directory , they are -rwxrwxrwx  (username) staff on files and  drwxrwxrwx  (username) staff for directories, - also check the update on the question

Comment: Maybe try running the command with the absolute path, so instead of `Tests/runner.ts` try `/full/path/to/Tests/runner.ts`..

Comment: nope, didn't work - I'm checking that the error occurs when executing scandir (check the error log in the end) - which is a PHP function, possibly PHP permissions have been disturbed and it no longer has access to certain directories

Comment: The problem you seem to have almost is like [this eslint issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6498) — or its eerily similar. The reason I say this is that if you look at the directories that your scandir is trying to traverse seem unusual (eg. `'/System/Library/User Template`, `/Library/Application Support/OpenVPN/profile'`). When you try running your command again maybe include the `--debug` flag to see if any additional info can be gleaned (not sure if it will work with yarn or not).

Comment: I ran the -- verbose on yarn run , not much info there - pasting that in the main question

Comment: I'm thinking maybe just - redo the mac - it would take a day but I'll probably get everything running again

Comment: You could, although maybe check your configuration files too (eg. `.yarnrc`), something is throwing it off into a directory that it shouldn't be accessing.

Comment: nothing in .yarnrc  - 

# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1


lastUpdateCheck 1518994787883

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some times it's the simple things that we miss, don't worry we have all been here.

This is a case of over thinking the issue, to steal a line from an Aussie beer commercial, you need to "UNDERTHINK IT". https://youtu.be/1MdAhVetBq8

The fact that your simple test script worked but the main test runner didn't, would have pointed me in the direction of stepping through the test runner script, rather than looking at yarn or any other culprit.

Turns out you were telling alsatian to search your entire hard drive for test cases, in which some folders it did not have permissions to access.

Change:

```
testSet.addTestsFromFiles('/**/*/*.spec.ts');
```

To:

```
testSet.addTestsFromFiles('**/*/*.spec.ts');
```

Or:

```
testSet.addTestsFromFiles('./**/*/*.spec.ts');
```

And all should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks brad - you saved from a potential re-install of the mac OS , after which I would have had the same problem! - now I feel really stupid lol